# Wrong assignment in string struct variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, c-strings

Please help me with this code. Why same name is assigned to all the different structs?
I'm noob to pointers and arrays in C.

```
struct student
{
    char *name;
    int reg_no;
};
typedef struct student student;

int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    char name[30];
    int rg;
    student students[5];
    int n = 0;
    while(choice != 'n')
    {
        printf("enter student's name\n>>");
        gets(name);
        printf("enter student's reg_no\n>>");
        scanf("%d",&rg);
        getchar();
        students[n].name = name;
        students[n].reg_no = rg;
        printf("enter details of more students (y/n)\n>>");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        getchar();
        n++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Details of student%d :\n",(i+1));
        printf("Name : %s\n",students[i].name );
        printf("Reg no. : %d\n\n",students[i].reg_no );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Running in console :**

[image]

Edit : Added student struct

Comment: How is `student` defined?

Comment: If `name` attribute of Student is a pointer, then it makes sense. You are assigning the address of name not the value

Comment: You probably need something like `strcpy(students[n].name, name)` instead of `students[n].name = name;`.

Comment: [Never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)!

Comment: [The use of gets() is deprecated!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: i have edited the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this statement

```
students[n].name = name;
```

the data member `name` of all elements of the array students gets the same address of the local variable `name`.

You need to declare the data member `name` of the structure as a character array and use either the C standard function `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy the content of the local variable `name` to the data member `name`.

For example

```
#define N 30

struct student
{
    char name[N];
    int reg_no;
};

typedef struct student student;

int main( void )
{
    char choice = 'y';
    char name[N];
    //…
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is an unsafe function and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the standard C function `fgets`.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//…

fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
name[strcspn( name, "\n" )] = '\0';

//…
strcpy( students[n].name, name );
```